# RegEx for to make a value optional and another value as required

Tags: c#, regex

```
string myQuery="RecordFiles/findrecords/$filter=userid eq 844427344589753 and
 recordid eq 55-278-278ac";
```

Given below is the regexpression I use to validate above query.

```
string myRegexQueryPattern = @"^(RecordFiles/findrecords/\$filter=userid eq)\s(?<userid>\S+)((\s(and recordid eq)\s(?<recordid >\S+))|(\s*$))";
```

how can I correct my regEx to make my recordId as optional and userId as required ?

```
 public static bool ValidateMyQuery(string query, Regex regex)
        {
            Match match = regex.Match(query);

            bool status = false;
            if (match.Success)
            {
                status = true;
            }
            return status;
        }
```

now my ValidateMyQuery returns true against myQuerystring .But if I am not sending recordId ,its returning false .I want to modify my regex so as to retun true when recordId 
is empty.

how can I correct my regEx to make my recordId as optional and userId as required ?

Comment: Have you tried the "?" operator?

Comment: Why do you have `|(\s*$)` at the end there?

Comment: Is that an OData url? If so, try using ODataUriParser to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to assert that userid is there you can use something like:

```
string myRegexQueryPattern = @"^RecordFiles/findrecords/\$filter=.*userid eq\s\S+.*";
```

Since recordid is optional we don't care if it's present or not.

Your regex suggest you want to capture the values however, if that is the case I'll update my answer.